# Has the Pauli Exclusion Principle been renamed? If so, what is it now called?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, electrons, terminology, pauli-exclusion-principle

> The force of touch is actually an emergent phenomenon that results from a complicated interaction between electromagnetism, and a feature of quantum theory originally called the Pauli exclusion principle.

-Richard Muller, MacArthur Foundation Fellow, Professor of Physics at UC Berkeley*

I was not aware that the Pauli Exclusion Principle is now called by any other name. Is it? And if so, what is the name that it is now called by?

*Link: https://www.quora.com/What-if-gravity-isnt-fundamental-force/answer/Richard-Muller-3

Comment: Never heard that anywhere

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why Prof. Muller used that phrasing, but it is definitely not to suggest that the Pauli Exclusion Principle has been renamed- after all, then he would have presumably just used the new name! My best guess is that the feature he wants to refer to is the requirement of antisymmetrization of the fermionic many-body wave function, which is sort of a generalization of the PEP.

Comment: There are a number of phenomena that are built on the PEP that can be used as shorthand at times, and one can appeal to the spin statistics theorem to *explain* the PEP. But neither approach takes away the utility of having a name to call the no-identical-fermions-in-identical-states principle.

Comment: @Rococo I agree. It occurred to me as well that it is probably a case of confusing phrasing, but I wanted to check. Thanks a lot!